# Interchange integral and limit in a subset

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

> Let $f(x), f_k(x) (k\geq 1)$ be non-negetive integrable functions on a measurable set $E$. If
> $$
> \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}f_k(x)=f(x)\quad a.e.
> $$
> and
> $$
> \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\int_Ef_k(x)\mathrm{d}x=\int_Ef(x)\mathrm{d}x.
> $$
> Prove that for any measurable subset $e\subset E$,
> $$
> \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\int_ef_k(x)\mathrm{d}x=\int_ef(x)\mathrm{d}x.
> $$

I have tried to use Fatou's lemma. By the lemma
$$
\varliminf_{k\rightarrow\infty}\int_e f_k(x)\mathrm{d}x\geq\int_e\varliminf_{k\rightarrow\infty}f_k(x)\mathrm{d}x=\int_Ef(x)\mathrm{d}x-\int_{E-e}f(x)\mathrm{d}x.
$$
But I don't know how to show the other direction.

Appreciate any hint or help!

Comment: Hint: Apply Fatou's Lemma to integrals over $e$ as well as integrals over $E-e$.